# Batch open JPGs in Preview

Tags: macos, applescript

I've had a look already on the forums for an answer to the problem but most of the time it is in the context of batch converting files (with disparate names). I only want to just open a range of JPEG files in Preview.

I capture images of particlar items in my workshop using "Workflow" for iOS. That has a script of its own that saves the files in the format 00000-0.JPG where the first five zeros are the article number and the final zero is the sequential order of that particalular item. e.g **78934-4.JPG** is the 4th photo of item "78934". The number of images for given item can vary a lot.

These all wind up in a folder (on my Mac) with several thousands other images, all with the same naming convention. I would like to speed up the process of finding and opening these (akin to being in Finder, selecting a range of images by hand and double-clicking the range and having them open in one "instance" or window of Preview - to minimise having to drag windows about) with AppleScript.

Here is what I've written so far...

```
tell application "Finder" to set myFiles to folder "Macintosh SSD:Users:me:ownCloud:Bilder_neu:Einzelbilder"

set file_extention to ".JPG"

set articleNumber to display dialog "Please enter article number" default answer "" with icon note buttons {"Cancel", "Continue"} default button "Continue"
```

I am not sure how to manage the "for loop" to find and then open the images.

Thanks for any help given

Comment: You said "The number of images for given item can vary a lot.", so what's "a lot"? Looking a your description with the first 5 digits being the article number and the last digit, the one after the '-' being shown as a single digit, there can only be 10 images of a given article number, 0-9 as the last digit. Is max count of 10 "a lot"? Is the pattern always numeric and confined to e.g. #####-#.JPG or can the pattern after the '-' be multi digit and if yes how many places? Also, what version of OS X/macOS are your using?

Comment: It is usually at least two images for each article. The article number is always five digits. The value after the hyphen would almost never exceed 9, so yes, in practical tems  #####-#.JPG would work in nearly all cases. Coudl the Terminal result of "ls #####-*" be applied here?

Comment: I've updated my answer for a use case if Preview is not the default handler for image files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following *example* **AppleScript** *code* assumes that the **macOS** *default* of images opening in **Preview** is still in play.

```
set theImages to quoted form of POSIX path of ¬
    ((path to home folder as string) & "ownCloud:Bilder_neu:Einzelbilder")

set articleNumber to text returned of ¬
    (display dialog "Please enter article number:" default answer ¬
        "" with icon note buttons {"Cancel", "Continue"} default button "Continue")

do shell script "find " & theImages & " -type f -iname '" & articleNumber & "-*.JPG' -exec open {} +"
```

If **Preview** is not the *default* handler for image files, then change the `do shell script` *command* to:

```
do shell script "open -a Preview $(find " & theImages & " -type f -iname '" & articleNumber & "-*.JPG')"
```

**Note that "*pure* AppleScript" is not required!**

---

**Note:** The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and does not employ any *error handling* and is meant only to show one of many ways accomplish a task. The onus is always upon the User to add/use appropriate *error handling* as needed/wanted.

Comment: Hey user3439894, just gave that a crack. It worked perfectly. Thanks for digging me out of that hole!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a pure AppleScript means of achieving your objective:

```
set ImagesFolder to "/Users/me/ownCloud/Bilder_neu/Einzelbilder"

set articleNumber to text returned of (display dialog ¬
    "Please enter article number" default answer ¬
    "" with icon note buttons {"Cancel", "Continue"} ¬
    default button "Continue")

tell application "System Events" to set JPGs to ¬
    path of every file in folder ImagesFolder whose ¬
    type identifier is "public.jpeg" and ¬
    name begins with (articleNumber & "-")

tell application "Preview" to open JPGs
```

Comment: The first solution seems to work better. It's quicker (in my case) and doesn't throw up permission error warnings. Thanks CJK for your help, all the same.

Comment: Hey CJK, I've updated my answer for a use case if Preview is not the default handler for image files and also made note that _pure_ AppleScript is not required. :)

Comment: @user3439894 Nice job with `open -a Preview $(find ...)`.  That's more sensible.  Although pure AppleScript is not required, isn't it more desirable generally ?  Or put another way, what made you approach solving this problem by employing shell commands, as opposed to grabbing the files through AppleScript (which was instinctively my first inclination) ?

Comment: Some Users never change the default so either way is sensible. - I have to say that I put 'Note that "pure AppleScript" is not required!' in my answer, after you posted yours, as kind of a joke. :) However, on a serious note, `do shell script` **is** an AppleScript _command_ and as such, there is absolutely nothing whatsoever wrong with its usage over a so called _pure_ AppleScript method or vise versa. I often defer to using `do shell script` because I usually can write what I want to achieve faster/easier and in less characters then with so called _pure_ AppleScript.

Comment: BTW... So called _pure_ AppleScript is not some sort of a badge. (Badges? We ain't got no badges! We don't need no badges! I don't have to show you any stinking badges!) :)

Comment: I think the sentiment behind my note about pure AppleScript was misinterpreted.  I have no problems integrating bash code with AppleScript, and you've seen me do it in many other scripts I've submitted on SE.  I simply described my solution as "pure AppleScript" to differentiate its methodology from yours, but not to imply that one was better than the other.  Although, as I did infer in the comment above, *visually*, I have a personal preference to pure AppleScript code; but *functionally*, one can achieve things with bash you just can't do in pure AppleScript, and often faster.

Comment: When you start off by saying 'Here's a pure AppleScript means of achieving your objective, and doesn't require Preview be the default application for opening jpeg images:' and then nothing else but code, after I posted the answer I did, yes I could have misinterpreted it if I had chosen to, but really I didn't, I was just trying to have some fun with it, seriously that's all! :) There are some user that really scoff about shelling out and I know you're not one of them! Besides that, do you know how hard it is to interject that movie quote into a conversation!? :)

Comment: I realised a little too late that my comment about *Preview* had a derogatory connotation in the way I worded it in reference to your answer.  I can tell you know I didn’t intentionally mean for that to be the case, but sometimes I type before I process my thoughts properly.  Anyway, it’s all good fun, and good learning.  I often attend to SE when I’m very tired, and in the wee hours of the morning.